# React Native: How to export a method with a return value?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, reactjs, react-native

What is the best way to export a method with a return value in React Native?

I know there is `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD`, but that only works for methods that are `(void)` and therefore don't return anything. Preferably I don't need to export the whole class, just a few methods.

The other option would be to have a callback, but I would like to avoid that if possible as it bloats up the code too much in my use case. Are there are any other options I might have missed?

Comment: I want to know how it was done. By using callbacks it was fine but other than that is there any alternative. And can we use those resolve and reject in RCT_EXPORT_METHOD???

Answer (score 20):

You can also now use promises, which tend to look a little nicer in your JS.

Objective C:

```
RCT_REMAP_METHOD(getThing, resolver: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
     rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
  if( condition ) {
    NSString *thingToReturn = @"ALL OK";
    resolve(thingToReturn);
  } else {
    reject([NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.companyname.app" code:0 userInfo:@{ @"text": @"something happend" }]);
  }
}
```

Then in JS:

```
async onPress() {
  try {
    const status = await CustomModule.getThing();
    // do something with status
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: How do i use status in //do something with status

When i am trying to print it in log it shows up like [Object object] 

Can you please explain how to print value of string ?

Comment: @chrishale how can you call and give data to getThing method from Objective C?

Answer (score 5):

Try return values with [Callbacks](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#callbacks)

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(findEvents:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
  NSArray *events = ...
  callback(@[[NSNull null], events]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems no way yet. That should be a feature to support.