# objc method is not being recognised on my JS side

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am trying to call my obj-c method to my js file.
It keeps throwing error that "updateUI is not a recognised object-c method"
What could be the mistake here???

```
@objc
  func updateUI(_ statisticsCollection: HKStatisticsCollection,  _ resolve: RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
                rejecter reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {
    
    struct Step {
        let id = UUID()
      var count: Int?
        var date: Date?
    }
   
      let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())!
      let endDate = Date()
      
      statisticsCollection.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate, to: endDate) { (statistics, stop) in
          
          let count = statistics.sumQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: .count())
          let steps = Int(count ?? 0)
        
        var stepCount = [Step]()
        var tempStepCount = Step(count: steps, date: Date())
          
        tempStepCount.count = steps
        tempStepCount.date = startDate
        stepCount.append(tempStepCount)
      }
    resolve(Step())
      
  }
```

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(updateUI: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                  rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
```

Update:
My Query to retrieve step count from HealthKit:

```
@objc
  func updateStepsCount(_ statisticsCollection: HKStatisticsCollection, _ resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
                        rejecter reject: @escaping (RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void) {
      
      let stepType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!
      
      let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())
      
      let anchorDate = Date.mondayAt12AM()
      
      let daily = DateComponents(day: 1)
      
      let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: Date(), options: .strictStartDate)
      
      let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: stepType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum, anchorDate: anchorDate, intervalComponents: daily)

          healthStore.execute(query)
      
  }
```

Is my Query correct? 
Do I call this directly in my JS file or do I need to append it an object??
I am very new to objc and swift and I need some help here.

Answer (score 1):

Your `@objc` `updateUI` method has 3 args, and you're invoking two.

Try

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(updateUI: (HKStatisticsCollection)someStatisticsCollection
                  resolve: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                  rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
```

Based on the code you provided it's impossible to tell where your `someStatisticsCollection` would come from in the js counterpart.

**Update**
I'm not really familiar with ReactNative, but based on [React Native: How to export a method with a return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29771622/5329717) it would seem it's not possible to return anything back to js.

Anyway your code for

```
@objc
  func updateStepsCount(_ statisticsCollection: HKStatisticsCollection, _ resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
                        rejecter reject: @escaping (RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void)
```

Seems not to use any of the arguments. If you'd like to know if that's a correct HealthKit query that deserves its own question.

To sum up, your `RCT_EXTERN_METHOD` signature must match method definition arguments. That's not the case in your code.

Comment: Thanks mate. Please check my updated question. struggling with this for days. I just want to read the step count from my JS files. I am not able to integrate everything. somehow I managed to get the HealthKit permissions to work.