# Objective-C react-native bridge: return a value (not a promise)

Tags: react-native

Can the react-native bridge for iOS (Objective-C) return a value (not a promise)? For example can I create a bridge function that corresponds to the following JS signature:

```
myFunc: (x: SomeMap): boolean
```

It appears to me that there's no way to do it: I have no issue with the argument -

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(myFunc:(NSDictionary *)x)
```

but seems cannot find the way to provide a return value.

Note: I haven't found any similar questions, except for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771622/react-native-how-to-export-a-method-with-a-return-value), but it's from 2015, and has no accepted answer. Hoping the things have changed since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible please understand that communication between languages ​​must be based on a `Like Message Channel` based on `postMessage/onmessage` events and of course to get the results back js/obj-c also have to wait for the other language to send `postMessage` that takes `t seconds` (delivery timeout and execution timeout) so it is required to return `Promise`

The reason for communication without returning `Promise` like `fs.readFileSync`, `input()` is that it blocks the entire system thread to wait for the result to return (similar to waiting for Promise but the whole thread has to wait. ) that's too silly (like js `alert`, `prompt`)

Imagine you have a request to save an image from the internet sent to `obj-c` and your `native` application freezes until the image is loaded by `obj-c` and saved to `Documents`. It's silly isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, nice to get a confirmation. I am an iOS developer, and was asked to confirm to certain JS interfaces, so discovering react-native on the fly. Sorry for noob questions.